# Multiple Email accounts in Outlook 2010 Professional PLus

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to setup a user to have two accounts in their Outlook 2010 Pro Plus. The first account is the default and setup and working fine. When i add the second account, it accepts the account info, verifies everything, but continues to ask for password each time the Outlook is opened. What am I missing?

thanx

UPDATE:

I have upgraded to Outlook Prof. Plus 2013 and still acts the same way. I have access to the accounts folders , but each time I open Outlook, it still asks for password

Comment: Have you checked your `Internet Email Settings` for the account?  Sometimes you need to tell Outlook to use the same credentials as your incoming mail server for outgoing.

Comment: What type of accounts are these? Exchange, POP3, IMAP, other?